# Обновление программы через сеть

Tags: сеть, java

Доброго времени суток. Вопрос такой. Имеется программа, по сути это jar упакованный в exe через Launch4j. И вот есть такая задача - программу эту нужно обновлять автоматически. Придумал хранить рядом с exe текстовичок с номером версии, программа бы его читала, сравнивала версии и выкидывала окошко, мол сходи на сервер, обновись, в случае более старой версии.
На сервер доступ идёт через сетевое окружение, то есть доступа по ftp или по http нет. Сам сервер крутится на Ubuntu, доступ из под Windows 7. При попытке открыть поток для чтения файла с указанием пути типа /server/my_file.txt программа отказывается читать текстовик ссылаясь на недоступный путь. Вопрос вот в чём: как правильно читать такие вот сетевые файлы? Может есть какие-то хитрые пути, о которых я просто не знаю?

Ну и вдогонку: можно ли при несовпадении версий прямо из моей программы заменить exe файлы и перезапустить exe на лету?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сам решил - сам отвечу, может кому пригодится.
Для такого обновления делаем вот что: указываем через URL путь к файлу на сервере(в моём случае "file://server/temp/prog/prog.exe"), создаем подключение и берем от него InputStream. Потом берем имя запускаемого локального exe, который будем обновлять, и создаем объект File из него и копируем файл с сервера в локальный файл.
А теперь самая вкусняшка - через Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook() добавляем новый объект Thread, в котором собственно и производится вызов exe в который мы копировали. Закрываем потоки и вызываем System.exit(0);
Вуаля, программа обновлена и перезапущена.